# How to say by/on the basis of?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, mathematics

In mathematics, the following phrase is common:

> By Theorem 5.6, the function is differentiable.

How do I say 'by' in Latin? I don't think 'ab' is appropriate to use here. One way is to put 'Theorem' into ablative case:

> Theoremate 5.6, functio est differentiabilis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using *propter* with accusative.
With your example:

> *Propter theorema 5.6 functio est differentiabilis.*

[This Latin mathematical text by Gauss](http://thelatinlibrary.com/gauss.html) has several instances of *propter*, for example:

> *propter [...] seriei convergentiam* — by convergence of the [...] series
>   *propter has rationes* — for these reasons
>   *propter [1]* — by equation [1]

The word *theorema* appears several times, but never in the sense of "by theorem", and *lemma* only appears as a title for two auxiliary results.
However, based on modern mathematical language and these examples from Gauss, it makes sense to me say *propter lemma/theorema*.

It might also be worthwhile to take a look at [*propter* in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=propter&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), especially II.B.1.